# Hangman: File I/O strings and lists python

Tags: python

Writing a hangman program in python and I've come across a problem when passing in a file that has multi word strings and single word strings.

FILE:

hello brown fox

dog

cat

water

jump

```
#initialize list
wordList = []
# get and open file
getFile = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
filename = open(getFile, "r")

def readWords(filename):
    for line in filename:
        # split any multi word line
        line.split()
        # add line to wordList
        wordList.append(line)
```

Yet the out put for wordList still reads:

```
wordList = ['hello brown fox\n', 'dog\n', 'cat\n', 'water\n', 'jump\n']
```

I am trying to make it so that 'hello brown fox' appears as 3 separate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you're having is that you're splitting but not saving the splitted line:

```
>>> a = "hello brown fox"
>>> a.split()
['hello', 'brown', 'fox']
>>> a
'hello brown fox'
>>>
```

so:

```
wordList.extend(line.split())
```

should do the trick for you

Comment: Ahh thank you! I tried appending line.split() before but that gave me a list of lists, I can't believe I forgot about extend.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this too complicated - just `.split` the entire file contents:

```
with open(getFile, "r") as f:
    words = f.read().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

The split function returns the result as a list, so appending it directly would probably not what you desire. You can try the following example:

```
def main():
    l_wordList = ['hello brown fox\n', 'dog\n', 'cat\n', 'water\n', 'jump\n']
    l_words_list = []
    l_word = ''
    for word in l_wordList:
        if isinstance(word.split(), list):
            for token in word.split():
                l_words_list.append(token)
        else:
            l_words_list.append(word)

    for word in l_words_list:
        print(word)

main()
```

And the result will be this

```
>>>
hello
brown
fox
dog
cat
water
jump
>>>
```

Regards,

Dariyoosh